# SQL Search Engine

Tags: php, mysql, sql, search

I know html and very very little of anything else.

I'm trying to put together a simple search engine for my website. I have 3 tables that I want to JOIN and then have the data available for searching.

```
MESSAGES (ID_TOPIC, SUBJECT)
TAGS (ID_TAG, TAG)
TAGS_LOG (ID_TAG, ID_TOPIC)
```

I'm trying to create an array with the three tables (MESSAGES, TAGS, and TAGS_LOG) so I can create a search engine that searches TAGS and outputs the data with MESSAGES.SUBJECT as a hyperlink where HYPERLINK is www.website.com/ID_TOPIC

I've looked all over and I've gotten close, but no money.

So far, I have;

```
CREATE TABLE new_table
  AS (SELECT tags.id_tag, messages.subject, tags.tag, tags_log.id_topic
      FROM messages, tags, tags_log);
```

which works for combining the information into a single table for searching. Next I created search.php;

```
<h2>Search</h2> 
 <form name="search" method="post" action="<?=$PHP_SELF?>">
 Seach for: <input type="text" name="find" /> in 
 <Select NAME="field">
 <Option VALUE="tag">tag</option>


 </Select>
 <input type="hidden" name="searching" value="yes" />
 <input type="submit" name="search" value="Search" />
 </form>

 <?
$field = $_POST['field'] ;
$find = $_POST['find'] ;
$searching = $_POST['searching'] ;

 //This is only displayed if they have submitted the form 
 if ($searching =="yes") 
 { 
 echo "<h2>Results</h2><p>"; 

 //If they did not enter a search term we give them an error 
 if ($find == "") 
 { 
 echo "<p>You forgot to enter a search term"; 
 exit; 
 } 

 // Otherwise we connect to our Database 
 mysql_connect("host", "user", "pass") or die(mysql_error()); 
 mysql_select_db("database") or die(mysql_error()); 

 // We preform a bit of filtering 
 $find = strtoupper($find); 
 $find = strip_tags($find); 
 $find = trim ($find); 

 //Now we search for our search term, in the field the user specified 
 $data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM new_table WHERE upper($field) LIKE'%$find%'"); 

 //And we display the results 
 while($result = mysql_fetch_array( $data )) 
 { 
 echo " "; 
 echo "Topic ID: {$result['id_topic']}"; 
 echo "<br>"; 
 Print "<a href=/index.php?topic={$result['id_topic']} target=new>{$result['subject']}    </a>";
 echo "<br>"; 
 echo "<br>";
 } 

 //This counts the number or results - and if there wasn't any it gives them a little message explaining that 
 $anymatches=mysql_num_rows($data); 
 if ($anymatches == 0) 
 { 
 echo "Sorry, but we can not find an entry to match your query<br><br>"; 
 } 

 //And we remind them what they searched for 
 echo "<b>Searched For:</b> " .$find; 
 } 
 ?>
```

But I'm having issues with dupes as in the Subject, I'm getting results from Subject and RE:Subject. I'm not sure how to weed out the "RE:Subject" so there's no duplicate entries.

Comment: pretty broad question. please try to include what you have done and where you are stuck,

Comment: What exactly is the question?

Comment: You say you have "looked all over" but have you googgled "sql join tutorial"? Learn some basics of SQL and you will be able to answer your own question.

Comment: I can see that you are a novice so I don't think this should be closed. You need to be more clear like @randy says. What is in the the three tables. And what should the SQL return. What will you do with this output? More precision please.

Answer (score 0):

Try: `SELECT TAGS.TAG, MESSAGES.SUBJECT, MESSAGES.ID_TOPIC FROM MESSAGES INNER JOIN TAGS_LOG ON MESSAGES.ID_TOPIC = TAGS_LOG.ID_TOPIC INNER JOIN TAGS ON TAGS_LOG.ID_TAG = TAGS.ID_TAG`

But as mentioned in the comments, this is an SQL 101 question. However it's not quite as trivial as suggested since there's an extra inner join in there that's bound to make any novice uncertain of themselves.

Comment: I omitted MESSAGSE.ID_TOPIC accidentally -- I've added it in.

Comment: You're adding comments to the wrong part of the thread -- add it above after your question, not after this answer.